# Asterisk initiate call through sip notify message

Tags: sip, asterisk, pbx

I have a Yealink ip phone on my desk and I want to remote control it so that I can place the calls from my computer instead than by typing the numbers directly on the phone. This link explains how to do it:

[How to dial or place a call using remote control | Yealink Support](http://support.yealink.com/faq/faqInfo?id=565#moreInfo)

There are **2** ways of doing it. One is sending a http request to the phone. And the other option is by sending a SIP notify message.

### A) Sending HTTP request (Works!)

1. First make sure the phone is configured to allow remote connections

[image]

2. Then just make this `wget` request

   ```
   wget --user admin --password PASSWORD_PHONE  http://IP_OF_PHONE/servlet?key=SPEAKER
   ```

After making that request the phone speaker key is pressed!

---

### B) Sending SIP Notify Message (Does NOT work)

This is the option I want to use because I do not want to store usernames and passwords. Also the ip address of the phone might change. **Anyways here is what I have tried and for some reason I cannot make this option work:**

1. I perform the first step that I did on part (A) by allowing the phone to be remote controled.
2. I connect the phone to my asterisk server and make sure it is connected.
   [image]
3. Now that the SIP peer Eduardo is connected I need to send it a SIP Notify Message with the body containing key=SPEAKER.
4. I open  `/etc/asterisk/sip_notify.conf` and add the following context:

   [test]
   Event=>ACTION-URI
   Content=>key=SPEAKER
5. I restart asterisk because I do not know how to reload sip_notify.conf

   ```
   asterisk -rx "core restart gracefully"
   ```
6. Then on asterisk CLI I type the following command in order to send the sip notify message:

   ```
   sip notify test Eduardo
   ```
7. when I run that command asterisk says: `Sending NOTIFY of type 'test' to 'Eduardo'` but the phone never presses the SPEAKER key! What could I be doing wrong?
8. Here is the sip message captured by Wireshark!

[image]

9. **Even though I am following the directions the SPEAKER key is not being pressed! What could I be doing wrong?**

---

### Helpful Info:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying all day I was able to figure it out! I was missing the content-type header!

Anyways here is the solution:

1. **sip_notify.conf file should contain:**

   ```
   [test]
   Content-Type=>message/sipfrag
   Event=>ACTION-URI
   Content=>key=SPEAKER
   ```

   The line `Content-Type=>message/sipfrag` is very important!
2. **Restart asterisk so that sip_notify.conf reloads**

   asterisk -rx "core restart gracefully"
3. **Now type this asterisk command:**

   ```
   sip notify test Eduardo
   ```

   where Eduardo is the SIP peer you want to send the key to
4. **A list of all the available keys can be found in here:**

   http://support.yealink.com/faq/faqInfo?id=173